# Is offering cross-site bounties allowed?

Tags: discussion, bounties, site-crossover

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754180/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-file-exists-in-the-directory) on Stack Overflow that starts with:

> NOTE: I'm also offering a bounty of 50 to 100 reputation on this problem. While I am unable to offer a bounty via StackOverflow due to my lack of reputation, I do have some reputation on Math.StackExchange that I can offer. If you can help me answer this question, I will pay you the bounty on the Math.StackExchange website.

That doesn't seem right, as the bounty would have to be awarded through an unrelated question on Math.SE. Should the note be removed from the question? What should be done if they proceed with this arrangement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### This is not right.

From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/366373):

> #### What is a bounty?
>
> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. This feature was designed to motivate answerers, and help questions get the answers they deserve.

Note that a bounty is given to an answer, not the answerer. A bounty given to an answer means that ***the answer which received the bounty deserves one***. Giving a bounty to an answer which a user *did not consider for a bounty before* skews everything.

I suggest that you comment on the post, and explain why this is not a good practice. Editing the note out might result in edit wars, so I don't know whether that would be a good idea or not. If the user goes on with the plan, maybe flag for moderator attention, as this is an abuse of the bounty system.